# Sorting a dictionary by value then by key

Tags: python

This seems like it has to be a dupe but my SO-searching-fu is poor today...

Say I have a dictionary of integer key/values, how can I sort the dictionary by the values descending, then by the key descending (for common values).

Input:

```
{12:2, 9:1,  14:2}
{100:1, 90:4, 99:3, 92:1, 101:1}
```

Output:

```
[(14,2), (12,2), (9,1)]  # output from print 
[(90,4), (99,3), (101,1), (100,1), (92,1)]
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
In [62]: y={100:1, 90:4, 99:3, 92:1, 101:1}
In [63]: sorted(y.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]), reverse=True)
Out[63]: [(90, 4), (99, 3), (101, 1), (100, 1), (92, 1)]
```

The `key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0])` tells `sorted` that for each item `x` in `y.items()`, use `(x[1],x[0])` as the proxy value to be sorted. Since `x` is of the form `(key,value)`, `(x[1],x[0])` yields `(value,key)`. This causes `sorted` to sort by `value` first, then by `key` for tie-breakers.

`reverse=True` tells `sorted` to present the result in descending, rather than ascending order.

See this [wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) for a great tutorial on sorting in Python.

PS. I tried using `key=reversed` instead, but `reversed(x)` returns an iterator, which does not compare as needed here.

Comment: I don't get the same output... I caught the first edition answer and it did exactly what I needed.

Comment: Nice, but a bit criptic... but I cannot think about anythin simpler.

Comment: what if I need to sort first by value ascendingly and then by key descendingly?

Comment: @user9875189 I'd use negative numbers to sort desc only the key (x[1],-x[0]). Should work on integers when n>0.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is more explicit:

```
>>> y = {100:1, 90:4, 99:3, 92:1, 101:1}
>>> reverse_comparison = lambda (a1, a2), (b1, b2):cmp((b2, b1), (a2, a1))
>>> sorted(y.items(), cmp=reverse_comparison)
[(90, 4), (99, 3), (101, 1), (100, 1), (92, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> d={100:1, 90:4, 99:3, 92:1, 101:1}
>>> sorted(d.items(), lambda a,b:b[1]-a[1] or a[0]-b[0])
```