# Sort dictionary first by key, then by value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I want to double sort a dictionary that might have int or tuple as keys.

```
d = {33:1, 44:1, (0,5):1  12:2, (1,2):2}
```

I want it sorted first by its values and secondly by its keys (if possible, not if one is tuple, and second is int).

can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Start here; http://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html. Sorting with lambda is also way more efficient than doing complex loops :). Multi-dimensional sorting might be a little bit harder tho, but just test a bit and shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: maybe this one can help:
>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742752/sorting-a-dictionary-by-value-then-by-key or even this one: >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919342/sorting-a-dictionary-by-key-then-value-python

Comment: Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742752/sorting-a-dictionary-by-value-then-by-key

Answer (score 4):

Or just

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda v: v[::-1])
```

**EDIT:**
Since OP requires the result as a dictionary

```
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda v: v[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = {33:1, 44:1, (0,5):1, 12:2, (1,2):2}
>>> {k:v for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda v: v[::-1])}
{(1, 2): 2, 33: 1, 44: 1, (0, 5): 1, 12: 2}
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict({k:v for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda v: v[::-1])})
OrderedDict([((1, 2), 2), (33, 1), (44, 1), ((0, 5), 1), (12, 2)])
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda v: v[::-1])
[(33, 1), (44, 1), ((0, 5), 1), (12, 2), ((1, 2), 2)]
```

Comment: Unless you use OrderedDict, the order of the sorted dictionary is not guaranteed

Comment: Dictionaries are inherently unsorted. OrderedDicts are also unsorted as soon as you modify an entry. Unless you make it a FrozenOrderedDict with immutable values, you SHOULD NOT return an OrderedDict. If you ask for a sorted view of something, return either a tuple, list, or generator, not a dictionary. Creating this OrderedDict is also a waste of clock cycles because the only method you care about is `__iter__`, which you get from the output of sorted()

Comment: @IceArdor, since OrderedDicts are sorted by the order the items are added to the dictionary, they are OK for OP.

Comment: @volcano I didn't interpret OP's question as needing the result as an OrderedDict. Sorted order does not matter when getting a value for a key. I stand by my previous statement. Either create your own dictionary class with a redefined `__iter__` or create a new object that is a tuple/list/generator to iterate over the sorted keys.

Comment: @IceArdor, order may matter when you iterate over keys. Tuples may be  cumbersome - chained indices have tendency to clutter the code and make it unreadable. And why reinvent the bicycle, when OrederedDictionary is there to use? BTW, the very fact that it is in the standard Python library shows that there is a valid usecase behind it.Creating new object? Totally anti-KISS

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
>>> d = {33:1, 44:1, (0,5):1, 12:2, (1,2):2}
>>> helper_dict = {}
>>> for k,v in d.items():
        helper_dict.setdefault(v,[]).append(k)    

>>> sorted_items = [(k,i) for k in sorted(helper_dict.keys()) for i in sorted(helper_dict[k]) ]
>>> sorted_items
[(1, 33), (1, 44), (1, (0, 5)), (2, 12), (2, (1, 2))]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should note that you may **not** sort a dictionary. You may get a list with keys/values sorted, but never the dictionary itself. You may find in the pydocs that

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs

Then, you may want to get a sorted list of keys:

```
# the .keys() returns a list with all the keys, and sorted() sorts them
#sorted_keys = sorted(d.keys()) this does not work since int's and tuples aren't of the same tipe
```

You can try this:

```
d_tuples = []
d_int = []
sorted_keys = []
for key in d.keys():
    # type() checks the variable type
    if type(key) == int:
        d_int.append(key)
    elif type(key) == tuple:
        d_tuples.append(key)
sorted_keys = d_tuples + sorted(d_int)
```

Or the sorted list of values:

```
sorted_values = sorted(d.values())
```