# Iterate over nested lists of dictionaries using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a bunch of text files containing meteorological data. Each text file stores a half-hour worth of data, which is 18000 observations (lines). There are 48 files in total (a full day), and I've stored all of the data in the following structure:

```
# all_data is a list of dictionaries, len=48 --> each dict represents one file

all_data = [{'time': 0026,
             'filename': 'file1.txt',
               # all_data['data'] is a list of dictionaries, len=18000
               # each dict in all_data['data'] represents one line of corresponding file
             'data': [{'x': 1.345, 'y': -0.779, 'z': 0.023, 'temp': 298.11},
                      {'x': 1.277, 'y': -0.731, 'z': 0.086, 'temp': 297.88},
                      ...,
                      {'x': 2.119, 'y': 1.332, 'z': -0.009, 'temp': 299.14}]
             },

             {'time': 0056,
              'filename': 'file2.txt',
              'data': [{'x': 1.216, 'y': -0648, 'z': 0.881, 'temp': 301.11},
                      {'x': 0.866, 'y': 0.001, 'z': 0.031, 'temp': 301.32},
                      ...,
                      {'x': 0.181, 'y': 0.498, 'z': 0.101, 'temp': 300.91}]
             },
             ...
             ]
```

Now I need to unpack it. I need to create a list of all values of x (`all_data[i]['data'][j]['x']`) in sequential order to use for plotting. Fortunately, the data is already stored in sequential order.

I know that I can simply do something like this to achieve my goal:

```
x_list = []
for dictionary in all_data:
    for record in dictionary['data']: # loop over list of dictionaries
         x_list.append(record['x'])
```

But I have to do something similar for many variables that I did not list here for simplicity's sake, and I really don't want to have to rewrite this loop 20 times nor hand-create 20 new lists.

**Is there a way to iterate over a nested data structure like this using list comprehension?**

I threw up a prayer and tried:

```
[x for x in all_data[i for i in len(all_data)]['data'][j for j in len(all_data[i]['data'])]
```

which of course didn't work. Any ideas?

Here's my **desired output**, which is just the values of 'x' in nested list 'data':

```
all_x = [1.345, 1.277, ..., 2.119, 1.216, 0.866, ..., 0.181, ...]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: @Ajax1234 edited, thank you.

Comment: No problem! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
all_data = [{'time': 0026, 'filename': 'file1.txt', 'data': [{'x': 1.345, 'y': -0.779, 'z': 0.023, 'temp': 298.11}, {'x': 1.277, 'y': -0.731, 'z': 0.086, 'temp': 297.88}, {'x': 2.119, 'y': 1.332, 'z': -0.009, 'temp': 299.14}]},
        {'time': 0056, 'filename': 'file2.txt','data': [{'x': 1.216, 'y': -648, 'z': 0.881, 'temp': 301.11}, {'x': 0.866, 'y': 0.001, 'z': 0.031, 'temp': 301.32},{'x': 0.181, 'y': 0.498, 'z': 0.101, 'temp': 300.91}]}]

x_data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[b["x"] for b in i["data"]] for i in all_data]))
print(x_data)
```

Output:

```
[1.345, 1.277, 2.119, 1.216, 0.866, 0.181]
```

Comment: Nice idea. I haven't worked with itertools much at all - never would have though of this. Thanks!

Comment: @nat5142 Glad to help! If this answer assisted you, please consider accepting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain
[ k['x'] for k in chain.from_iterable([ i['data'] for i in all_data ]) ]
```

Comment: Great idea, I'll give this a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Got a downvote from someone. Downvoter, please explain, I'll correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Pandas, this can be a great way of accomplishing what you want. Running

`dataDfList = [pandas.DataFrame(f['data']) for f in all_data]`

Will generate a list of DataFrames, each looking like:

`|      |  temp  | x     | y      | z      | 
|------|--------|-------|--------|--------| 
| 0    | 298.11 | 1.345 | -0.779 | 0.023  | 
| 1    | 297.88 | 1.277 | -0.731 | 0.086  | 
| 2    | 299.14 | 2.119 | 1.332  | -0.009 |`

Each of these can then be easily plotted. You could also accomplish this with a MultiIndex, e.g. by stacking the list of dataframes using `pandas.concat(dataDfList)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Given Pandas' power and structure I figured it would make the answer to my question pretty easy. I'll hang onto that as a fallback, but for now I'm gonna try to work through it with the current data structure

Comment: Given your desire is plotting, using Pandas is useful. You can plot directly or export values to numpy ndarray and plot that values. Handling columns is easier too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want an output is:

1. a list
2. each element is a sublist which is value of variable x -> z, temp

not just list values of `x`.

Then this is your code:

```
values = [row.values() for day in all_data for row in day['data']]
```

With each item in `values` is a list of values of variable from x -> z/temp, or a matrix of vector value.

For your above sample data, the output is:

```
[[-0.779, 1.345, 0.023, 298.11], [-0.731, 1.277, 0.086, 297.88], [1.332, 2.119, -0.009, 299.14], [-0.648, 1.216, 0.881, 301.11], [0.001, 0.866, 0.031, 301.32], [0.498, 0.181, 0.101, 300.91]]
```

corresponding to `['x', 'y', 'z', 'temp']` variables.

EDIT: if you want to extracts values for one variable, use `numpy`, convert the the output to array and extract the corresponding column.

Comment: This is a clever way of doing it. Unfortunately I need to extract a specific value to insert into a list, leaving me with a list of all x variables, a list of all y variables, a list of all z variables, and a list of all temp variables. Because dictionaries aren't stored in order, I'd need to call a dictionary key to ensure that I'm getting the right values. Otherwise, iterating over your output and making `x = [i[0] for i in values]` could leave me with the wrong resulting dataset.

Comment: Totally forgot about the order of dictionary. Then one way to do that is sorted the key, val by their key (variable name). `[[v for k, v in sorted(row.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))] for day in all_data for row in day['data']]` shoudld do it? Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7742808/3444923