# Printing the max key with the most common value

Tags: python

I need to find the most common number in string

```
string = '43534353545466'
d = {}
for i in set(string):
    d[i] = string.count(i)

print(max(d, key=d.get), max(d.values()))
```

But i have problem with the second task: If there are a few numbers that occurs the same amount of times, i need to print the biggest one(In this example: '5:4'). What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve the second task.

Answer (score 2):

This is practically the same as [Sorting a dictionary by value then by key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7742752/4518341), just using `max` instead of sorting.

```
>>> max(d.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0]))
('5', 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

```py
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(string)
most = c.most_common(1)[0][1]
max((i for i in c.most_common() if i[1] == most), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

```
('5', 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to import any modules (not that you shouldn't) you could do this:

```
string = '43534353545466'

d = {k:string.count(k) for k in set(string)}

c, n = sorted((v, k) for k, v in d.items())[-1]

print(f'Digit {n} occurs {c} times')
```

**Output:**

```
Digit 5 occurs 4 times
```